# Why is the Server Path not Valid?

Tags: server, path, captcha

I am hosting a client site on HostGator running Plesk. I got the server path from their documentation and confirmed it with tech support, however, when I enter the server path in the necessary locations (Captcha, Templates, etc.) I get the following error:

> The following path you submitted is not valid

The path I have entered is:

> /var/www/vhosts/web.clientname.com/domain/themes/

Is there anyone with experience on HostGator Plesk that can provide insight into why I get the error? And more importantly, how to resolve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upload a file called `test.php` in their respective folders with the following code:-

```
<?php
   echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
?>
```

Then open those files in your browser and see what the echo'd path is. That should be the thing you set.

Comment: No worries, glad it fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with HostGator, but perhaps it's
`/var/www/vhosts/web.clientname.com/domain/public_html/themes/`
or
`/var/www/vhosts/web.clientname.com/domain/htdocs/themes/`

Comment: Hi Yuri, this is a good suggestion, however, the structure is such that domain is equivalent to htdocs. This allows for multiple sites. Thanks.